# URL rewriting messes css/js up

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

what I'm trying to achieve is

`domain.com/register/free`

that would be

`domain.com/register.php?type=free`

When I go go `domain.com/register` the page loads fine, but if I put the next `/free` part it cant find the css or js images etc. Not too sure where I have gone wrong but this is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^register$ register.php
RewriteRule ^register/$ register.php

RewriteRule ^register/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)$ register.php?type=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can improve your rules

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^register/?$ register.php [L]
RewriteRule ^register/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ register.php?type=$1 [L]
```

Then, since you create a virtual folder because of your rule (`/register/`) and you're using *relative* paths (instead of **absolute** paths), your links are not good anymore.

Two options (both using **absolute** paths):

- add a leading slash for all your css (and js, img, etc) links.
  e.g: `href="/css/style.css"` instead of `href="css/style.css"`
- add this tag just after `<head>` in all your concerned pages: `<base href="/">` (this will avoid you to replace each link one by one)